# How to execute multiple string SQL command in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Actually I want to make the button click and execute those 2 queries in one-time manner.

```
string Query = "UPDATE harga_semasa SET we_buy='" + this.textBox1.Text + "',we_sell='" + this.textBox2.Text + "', idharga_semasa='" + this.label5.Text + "' WHERE type='" + this.label1.Text + "';";
string Query2 = "UPDATE harga_semasa SET we_buy='" + this.textBox3.Text + "',we_sell='" + this.textBox4.Text + "', idharga_semasa='" + this.label10.Text + "' WHERE type='" + this.label4.Text + "';";

MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query2, MyConn2);
MySqlCommand MyCommand1 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
MyConn2.Open();
MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
MyReader2 = MyCommand1.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
while (MyReader2.Read())
{
}
MyConn2.Close();
```

How do I execute multiple with this code? I try to add some data to the existing table which is already inserted. I am newbie in C# and start to understand some of the code.

Comment: Before you do that, try one sql command without a glaring *sql injection* attack vector by using  parameterized query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reuse the same connection with multiple `MySqlDataReader` objects simultaneously: https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/connection-reuse/

Since your code doesn't actually need the `MySqlDataReader`, a simple fix is to use `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute your `UPDATE` statements.

You should also use parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection and `using` statements to close the connection automatically

```cs
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE harga_semasa SET we_buy=@we_buy, we_sell=@we_sell, idharga_semasa=@idharga_semasa WHERE type=@type;", connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@we_buy", this.textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@we_sell", this.textBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idharga_semasa ", this.label5.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", this.label1.Text);

        // use this to run the query (without MySqlDataReader)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // execute your second query the same way here

    MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
}
```